# Creating the Previews of MS Office Files like word excel and PPT in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, ms-office

How can I create the preview image for MS Office files like word, excel, power point in cocoa. Can anyone suggest me on this like how to handle those file? I tried using the Bitmap representation of the .doc files. It didn't work. Which API I can use?

Comment: Anyone can give me some suggestion regarding how to create the preview images of the .doc , .txt, .ppt, .xls...... in cocoa... Any suggestion is appreciable. I used NSImage+QuickLook by Matt Gemmell. In that we cannot get the preview image of each page or each slide incase of multipage documents. How can i hold the data of the file. If i store the MS word file as NSData how can i get the information of .doc file... Like how many pages it conatins and all.. How can i proceed...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use Quick Look. There is a great example of using Quick Look to generate an `NSImage` you can display anywhere with [this code from Matt Gemmell](http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/29/how-to-get-a-quick-look-preview-as-an-nsimage)

Look inside the snippets/QuickLook folder in the ZIP file he links to, and you'll find his code for getting the Quick Look preview for any file. Leopard and Snow Leopard can preview most Office files out of the box without needing Office to be installed.

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for replying... But in that it creates preview of first page of multipage document . and also i dint get How to use for doc and powerpoint files. I used that code for creating previews of images . It works superb. The previews been creared are ultimate. But only thing how can i get the details of the .pps file , like how many slides it contains and all. I need to create preview of each slide ... Any suggestions on this????